# Rails controller for REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

In a rails controller, `GET /objects/` routes to `index`, `POST /objects` routes to `create`, `GET /objects/<id>` routes to `show`. What do `PUT /objects/<id>` and `PATCH /objects/<id>` route to?

Comment: They will typically go to `.update`.

Comment: @rmlockerd Both of them will go to the same function? Hmm...I guess that makes sense. Thanks. Will you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

By convention (for example if you use the `resources` helper in `config/routes.rb`), `PUT` and `PATCH` will both route to the `.update` method on the controller. So:

```rb
namespace :api do
  resources :posts
end
```

Will give you:

```sh
% r routes
...
PUT /api/posts/:id(.:format) api/posts#update
PATCH /api/posts/:id(.:format) api/posts#update
```

Comment: oh yah...I forgot I could just see this with `rails routes`. Thanks for the answer.